# Linux software raid GUI monitor for GNOME

Tags: linux, raid, storage, software-raid, mdadm

I prefer mdadm to administrate my raid and I currently use a script to see the raid status.
Running a (php)script to see the status is not exactly the most smooth experience for me so I have been looking for a GUI app / gnome gadget that shows me the current raid status.
So far I have not found anything that I like.
What do YOU use and recommend for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI + RAID = strange.

Are you sitting 24/7 in front of the monitor to watch when it breaks? For this case you have monitoring software that alerts you by an appropriate channel (email, SMS, RSS, ...). But for me a GUI is not in the list of appropriate channels.

But probably you like [raidmonitor](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Monitoring/raidmonitor-1414.shtml).

Comment: I'd guess (hope?) that this is a higher end workstation. I've used RAID on my personal desktop before. If it were a workstation at his job, I think it would fall within the acceptability of this site

Comment: No, I am not sitting 24/7 in front of this computer but I log into a gnome session from various locations every now and then. Mail is not a option for me. So you see the simplest thing for me is something graphical that indicates the current status. There already exists temperature, network, cpu load, disk load gadgets and by pplying your logic none of them should exists. I understand there are better ways to deal with notifications for raid but I do at this time prefer a GUI tool for the job. Thanks for your suggestion. I will check out raid monitor.

Comment: You got it. Gadgets are not appropriate to monitor the system status.